# Cluster point of a net is a limit of a subnet

Tags: general-topology, nets

A point $c\in X$ is a *cluster point* of the net $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ if, for every neighborhood $U$ of $c$ and for any $d_0\in D$ there exists $d\ge d_0$ such that $x_d\in U$. In the other words, $x_d$ is frequently (cofinally) in $U$.

**Question:** How to show that for any cluster point $c$ of $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ there is a [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnet_(mathematics)) converging to $c$?

Since this result is often used in connection with nets, I considered useful to have the proof available somewhere on the site.

It is worth mentioning that different definitions of subnet are commonly used: [Different definitions of subnet](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1126609). (Although for our purpose they are similar in the sense that they give the same set of limits of convergent subnets.)

Answer (score 2):

Let us define the directed set
$$D'=\{(U,d); U\text{ is a neighborhood of }c, d\in D, x_d\in U\}$$
with the natural ordering, i.e.,
$$(U,d)\le (U',d') \Leftrightarrow (U\supseteq U') \land (d\le d').$$
This is indeed a directed set, if $x_{d_1}\in U_1$ and $x_{d_2}\in U_2$ then there is $d\in D$ such that $d\ge d_1$, $d\ge d_2$ and $x_d\in U_1\cap U_2$.

Let us define $f\colon D'\to D$ by $f(U,d)=d$. The map $f$ is clearly cofinal and monotone. We see that $x_{(U,d)}=x_d$ and that $(x_{(U,d)})$ is a subnet of $(x_d)$.

---

Two or three various notions of subnet are commonly used.<sup>1</sup> But we have found a map which is both monotone and cofinal - which is the most restrictive of the three definitions.

---

<sup>1</sup>I wrote two or three since AA-subnet is mentioned less frequently, so this definition is probably less common. See, for example: [Different definitions of subnet](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1126609) on this site, my [notes on various definition of subnets](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/texty/rozne/topo/subnets2.pdf) which are based on [Schechter's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=eqUv3Bcd56EC&pg=PA174).

Comment: Yes, the standard product trick and using reversely ordered neighbourhoods. To see that $x \circ f$ converges to $c$: For $U$ an open neighbourhood of $c$, define $d' = (U,d)$ for any $d \in D$, and if $(V,d') \ge (U,d)$ we have $x_{d' } \in V \subseteq U$ etc.

Comment: Should the last line before the second paragraph have $x_{d}\in U_{1}\cap U_{2}$ as opposed to $d\in U_{1}\cap U_{2}$ ?

Comment: @TravisCCuvelier Thanks for noticing.